# State data is being duplicated after using setState inside of componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, state

I'm making a get() request to firestore to get data. I am able to store the data in my component state but each time I try to access the data, it shows as duplicated. How can I prevent it? Thanks.

``

```html
import React from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/firebase';

class ViewLists extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listData: []
    };
  }
     
 componentDidMount(){
  fire.firestore().collection('restaurantList')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    const lists = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    this.setState({ listData: lists });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { listData } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {listData.map(list => console.log(list.user))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ViewLists;
```

``

Comment: do `{listData: [...lists]}` instead of what you're doing

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't quite work